# What is the data type of the name of a struct

Tags: c, oop, types, struct, instanceof

If I wanted to make a function which takes the name of a struct as an argument, what would the method signature look like?

```
typedef struct Class{
} Class;

main()
{
    Class *a = malloc(Class);
    return instanceOf(a, Class);
}
```

What would the declaration of `instanceOf` look like?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pass types to functions in C. However, you can simulate this behaviour using macros:

```
#define new_instance(t) (malloc(sizeof(t)))

Class *instance = new_instance(Class);
```

Comment: Not even with type casts? I read something [here](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf) about casting them to void pointers. Will the compiler always give out an error or can the identifier "Class" be casted to a pointer to somewhere...

Comment: No, You CAN'T PASS TYPES TO FUNCTIONS AS ARGUMENTS.

Comment: @DavidNathan The approach described in that document doesn't pass around types/struct names as values. It creates values (of struct types) to represent classes and passes those around. As H2CO3 said, you can't pass types as function arguments (or store them in variables or use them in any other context where values are used).

Comment: This is a similar concept to that of Objective-C: regarding objects as instances of classes, it's sufficient to create a class descriptor structure, with the instance size, superclass, instance variables and methods defined, then use this structure for OO operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define type(x) #x

typedef struct Class{
    char* type;
} Class;

Class *Class_new(){
    Class *v;
    v=(Class*)malloc(sizeof(Class));
    v->type = "Class";
    return v;
}

void Class_free(Class *a){
    free(a);
}
int instanceOf(Class *a, const char* type){
    return strcmp(a->type, type) == 0;
}

int main(){
    Class *a = Class_new();
    printf("%s\n", instanceOf(a, type(Class)) ? "YES" : "NO");
    Class_free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Encode and encapsulate the type within a nested structure when you create it.

struct struct_info
{
    int type;
    char name[32];
} 

struct mystruct
{
    struct struct_info;
}
```